# match all tags after a specific tag

Tags: regex, textmate

I'm beating this dead horse here:

```
<p style='margin: 5px 0;'>I wan't be matched!</p>
<p style='margin: 5px 0;'>me 2!</p>
<ul>
    <li>
      <b>Lorem</b>
      ipsum sit dolor amet
    </li>

    <li>
      <b>Lorem</b>
      ipsum sit dolor amet
    </li>

    <li>
      <b>Lorem</b>
      ipsum sit dolor amet
    </li>

    <li>
      <b>Lorem</b>
      ipsum sit dolor amet
    </li>

    <p style='margin: 5px 0;'>can i haz regex</p>
    <p style='margin: 5px 0;'>NO! you can't</p>
    <li>
      <b>Lorem</b>
      ipsum sit dolor amet
    </li>   
<ul>
```

from that I need a regex that changes all the

```
    <p style='margin: 5px 0;'>can i haz regex</p>
```

after the  tag and converts it into

```
    <li>can i haz regex</li>
```

simple as that, but considering that I'm a real noob at regex, I can't get it done.

I was trying with look behind expression, but with no success

```
  (?m:(?<=(.*?<ul>.*?)(<p style='margin: 5px 0;'>.*?</p>)+)
```

it's about 2hrs that I'm trying to figure it out, but I can't really seem to make it work.
so thanks in advance to anyone who can explain me how this thing should be settled to work out. :)

Comment: I would suggest using something besides regular expressions to parse HTML or XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: just read that before posting but it's no use to me, sadly.

Comment: which part is no use? The part that tells you that it won't work or the part that tells you to use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: it's no use because I'm not trying to *parse* anything here, I just need to *match* something, I've already matched an entire HTML file via regex, so it's arguable what's said in that post. I can see that regex can have some limitations, but this doesn't mean that "it can't be used to parse HTML"

Comment: parsing the document is part of matching, and the problem is not that regex *can't* be used to parse HTML but that it **shouldn't** be used to parse HTML. There are better, less complicated ways of doing this that only involve a small speed tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines to change must be between `<ul>` and `</ul>`, then you could try something like the following `sed` command:

```
sed "/<ul>/,/<\/ul>/ s|<p style='margin: 5px 0;'>\(.*\)</p>|<li>\1</li>|g" test.html
```

This isn't using **only** regex in the sense that I specify an address range, too.
You really need to be careful using these tools with HTML, though, I agree with the comments. You don't want to depend on whitespaces or how the tags sit on lines, to begin with.

Also, maybe you could tell us what language you are using (if it matters).

Comment: I know the risks of basing a system on regex, but I need to convert xmls into sql statements, and considering all the patterns that I've to count, and the little time that I've to get the job done, this seemed to be the only praticable option. anyway it works like a charm! thanks so much :)